# Определение геопозиции react-yandex-maps

Tags: reactjs, геолокация

В документации есть пример кода с картой и кнопкой геопозиции:

```js
<YMaps>
  <Map
    defaultState={{
      center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
      zoom: 9,
      controls: [],
    }}
  >
    <GeolocationControl options={{ float: "left" }} />
  </Map>
</YMaps>;
```

А как поймать результат определения геопозиции (координаты)?